# Convert centimeters to degrees

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am working on an autonomous robot. This robot can recognize an object and pick it up. I have a pickup algorithm already. 
$$x=D\cos(θ) \quad \text{and} \quad y=D\sin(θ),$$ where $D$ is the length of my robot arm and $θ$ is the angle that it moved in radians.

This code gives an understanding of where the arm is on the Cartesian plane. I have an object detection system and using ultrasonic sensor I want it to stop $2 \,\text{cm}$ before the object. If the robot is located at the origin, $(0, 0)$, and the object is $2 \,\text{cm}$ from me, I want to know its $(x, y)$ coordinates. How do I convert from centimeters to degrees so I can know the object's $x$ and $y$ values?

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question, but you can use the fact that a radian has a length equal to the radius, in your case, the length of the robot arm, D1.

Comment: I get your point but the length of the arm can be smaller

Comment: OK, I guess that's the beauty of radians. Whatever the length of the arm (whether it is fully extended or not), the length of the radian in cm is equal to that of the radius. A fully extended arm, say 100 cms long, moved 1 radian each will travel precisely 100 cms. If the arm is contract to just 10 cms long, it will travel by just 10 cms.

Comment: Clarifications needed: What are your coordinates? In which direction is the object from you? What does "stop 2cm before" mean - "before" in which direction? Does the arm change length or not? Is the grid measured in cm (probably yes)? (And perhaps a diagram would help.)

Answer (score 1):

You need one other piece of data.  You know you are $2$ cm from the object but you have not told us you know what angle it is at.  Without that it could be anywhere on a $2$ cm circle around your current point.  It sounds like you are approaching it, so it can't be behind you but that still leaves a large range.  You know $D=2$ but you have no data to evaluate $\theta$ in what you have given.